# Does CiviCRM work with Ninja Forms?

Tags: wordpress, forms

In wordpress, when setting up a ninja form text block I get the following error. It shows up next to the "Add Media" button so I assume that it is trying to add a Civicrm button and fails.

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.shortcodes.modal.php on line 170 Call Stack: 0.0000 239040 1. {main}() /var/www/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php:0 0.1404 4172272 2. do_action() /var/www/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php:89 0.1404 4173800 3. call_user_func_array() /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php:503 0.1404 4173944 4. ninja_forms_new_field() /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php:503 0.1940 4190192 5. ninja_forms_return_echo() /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/includes/admin/ajax.php:193 0.1940 4207304 6. call_user_func_array() /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/includes/functions.php:7 0.1940 4207768 7. ninja_forms_edit_field() /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/includes/functions.php:7 0.1941 4207952 8. do_action() /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/includes/admin/edit-field/edit-field.php:6 0.1941 4209592 9. call_user_func_array() /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php:503 0.1941 4209760 10. ninja_forms_edit_field_output_li() /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php:503 0.1958 4214568 11. nf_output_registered_field_settings() /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/includes/admin/edit-field/li.php:123 0.1987 4218784 12. ninja_forms_edit_field_el_output() /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/includes/admin/edit-field/li.php:419 0.1993 4221088 13. wp_editor() /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/includes/admin/edit-field/edit-field.php:132 0.1995 4230840 14. _WP_Editors::editor() /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/general-template.php:2565 0.2024 4238472 15. do_action() /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php:222 0.2096 4250120 16. call_user_func_array() /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php:503 0.2096 4250272 17. CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Shortcodes_Modal->add_form_button() /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php:503 0.2096 4250344 18. CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Shortcodes_Modal->post_type_has_button() /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.shortcodes.modal.php:101

It prevents the text field from being saved in the form.  In this case I don't need any civicrm processing in the form so it does not need to be there but I don't know how to remove it.  Has anyone dealt with this before?

Versions: Wordpress 4.3.1, Civicrm 4.6.8, Ninja forms 2.9.28

Comment: Can you add the versions of WordPress, CiviCRM and Ninja Forms?

Comment: Interesting. So it's the wp_editor() function that's triggering the error on an admin screen that has no post type set.

Answer (score 2):

Fixing this will require a change to the Civi-WP plugin. In the meantime, put the following code on a new line below the one that reads `$screen = get_current_screen();` which should be at line 164 of 'civicrm.shortcodes.modal.php'.

```
if ( ! isset( $screen->post_type ) ) return;
```

That should mean your fields are saved again.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you!